# problema para separar los atributos por columnas en archivo .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

El programa debe leer "una tabla" en python y luego escribirla en un archivo csv, lo que tengo hasta momento es:

Lo que está arriba del código principal, son funciones que simplemente me sirven para agregar nombres, edades y puntajes (no veo necesario agregarlo).

```
############################## Programa principal ##############################


# Se pedirá la cantidad de personas que serán ingresadas.
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("\nIngrese el número de personas:   "))

        if type(n) is int and n > 0:
            break
        else:
            print("\nIngrese un número de personas válido (mayor de 0)")
    except ValueError:
        print("\nERROR\nPor  favor solo ingrese números enteros "
              "que sen mayores de cero")

# Se guarda la lista creada con los nombres que ingresó el usuario.
Nombres = ingresar_nombre(n)
# Se guarda la lista creada con las edades que ingresó el usuario.
Edades = ingresar_edad(n)
# Se guarda la lista creada con los puntajes que ingresó el usuario.
Puntajes = ingresar_puntaje(n)

# Se empaquetan los datos anteriores en una sola lista la cual en cada posición
# contiene una tupla con (Nombre, Edad, puntaje).
carpeta = zip(Nombres, Edades, Puntajes)

# Ordena la todos los elemetos de la lista.
carpeta_ord = sorted(carpeta)
titulos = ["NOMBRE", "EDAD", "PUNTAJE"]

# Imprime los títulos de la tabla
print('\n{:^20}{:^20}{:^20}'.format("NOMBRE", "EDAD", "PUNTAJE"))

# Imprime los elementos correspondientes a cada columna de la tabla.
for nombre, edad, puntaje in carpeta_ord:
    print("{:^20}{:^20}{:^20}".format(nombre, edad, puntaje))

# Crea el archivo csv

archivo = open('tabla.csv', 'w', newline="")
salida = csv.writer(archivo)
salida.writerow(titulos)
salida.writerows(carpeta_ord)
del salida

archivo.close()
```

El programa me imprime esta "tabla" (aclaro que no puedo usar pandas o librerías similares):

[image: El programa me imprime esta "tabla" (aclaro que no puedo usar pandas o librerías similares):]

Y en excel me pone esto, necesito que todo me quede separado en las columnas correspondientes.

[image: Y en excel me pone esto, necesito que todo me quede separado en las columnas correspondientes.]

¿Cómo hago para que cada atributo me lo ponga en una columna diferente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richard entiendo que el output que tenes está bien, lo que pasa es que al abrirlo con exel tenes que poner o decirle utilizar comas como separadores, te comparto dos links sobre el tema:

1 - https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Importar-o-exportar-archivos-de-texto-txt-o-csv-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

2 - http://www.forosdelweb.com/f90/cambiar-delimitador-csv-excel-996168/

espero que te ayude

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de guardar los datos en el fichero separa los datos con punto y coma (`;`) asi:

```
Nombre;Edad;Puntaje
Samir;23;100
Andres;20;23
Jairo;18;73
```